# Web Api core 2.0 Controller method input parameter validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How do you validate a `JObject` input parameter to a controller method? I am wondering is there any framework supported functions to validate easily?

Right now I am validating against null, if it is not null the `JObject` is parsed and populated the DTO object and  complete the business process.

My controller method looks like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]JObject jObject)
{
    try
    {
        if (jObject != null)
        {                    
            TokenDTO SiBagToken = await _account.Login(jObject);

            return SuccessStatusCode;

        }
        else
        {
            return NoContentStatusCode;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        return errorstatuscode;

    }          

}
```

Here is the DTO object looks like:

```
public class AccountDTO
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string oldPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the framework parse the desired object model by making it a parameter of the action.

Validation attributes can be applied to the DTO

For example

```
public class AccountDTO {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Your {0} must be contain between {2} and {1} characters.", MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string oldPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And verified in the action using the controller's `ModelState`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]AccountDTO model) {
    try {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {  
            TokenDTO SiBagToken = await _account.Login(model);
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);            
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return errorstatuscode;
    }          
}
```

Comment: Starting from version 2.1 there's no need for the manual IsValid check when annotated with [ApiController]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @ChristophLütjen yes that is if you are using an `[ApiController]`, but not by default. The information you provided is still accurate though.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

So If I change the input parameter from JObject to DTO object, will the Angular UI understands?

Comment: @Prasad the DTO class is for the Server side. The JSON sent by the client will be parsed by the framework and passed to the controller action.